# Defining folder and parameters in process.start?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a simple launcher for anti-virus programs using c#, and having a bit of difficulty understanding what im missing.

i want to run cmd.exe, then run sav32cli.exe with the argument "e:" so it always scans drive E. this is located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Sophos\Sophos Anti-Virus"

this is the line I have, but when I run it the program closes.

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", "cd "c:/Program Files (x86)/Sophos/Sophos Anti-Virus/" && sav32cli.exe e: ");

or is there a better suited process for this?

Comment: Look at the class [ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo). You could find  the plumbing necessary to solve your problem. An instance of ProcessStartInfo could be passed as parameter to the Process constructor

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `cd` to direct to the folder. Just use absolute path to access the exe.

```
Process p = new Process();
// the full path of exe
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:/Program Files (x86)/Sophos/Sophos Anti-Virus/sav32cli.exe";
// set the argument
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "e:";
p.Start();
```